# Is there a way to achieve master/slave type dependent observables in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got 2 fields in my model that have a master/slave type relationship.

If the master updates the slave should take the update too.

If the slave updates the master is unaffected.

I've managed to implement this with a manual subscription - http://jsfiddle.net/ProggerPete/XNUPj/

But I'm wondering if I could achieve the same result without the manual binding. The reason I'm wanting it is I'd prefer not to have to unbind my manual subscriptions when i'm destroying my view.

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I would say that the manual subscription is the most straightforward approach to your question.

However, it is pretty easy to create your own custom observable that encapsulates this functionality and handles updating both the master and slave in a writeable dependentObservable.  It might look something like this:

```
function customObservable(initialValue) {
    var _source = ko.observable(initialValue),
        _local = ko.observable(initialValue),
        result = ko.dependentObservable({
            read: _source,
            write: function(newValue) {
               _source(newValue);
               _local(newValue); 
            }
        });

    result.local = _local;

    return result;
}
```

and you would use it like:

```
var viewModel = {
    source: customObservable("sourceValue")
};
```

The customObservable (call it whatever you want) returns a writeable dependentObservable that will update both values that you can bind against as `source`.  The local value is also exposed as `source.local`.

So, you would use this in your scenario like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/67pDS/

I am not sure how you want to use this functionality though.  If you are looking for the ability to accept/cancel edits to an observable, then you might want to look at [this](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html) custom observable.

Snippet to show disposal in custom binding:

```
        var subscription = oComboBoxModel.value.subscribe(updateBestMatchFromValue, oComboBoxModel);

        //handle disposal (if ko.cleanNode is called on the element)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function(){
              subscription.dispose();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. In the scenario I have I'm not able to modify the original view model to change the observable to a custom observable. I'm working on a combobox binding and I'd like the original view model to need anything tricky. http://jsfiddle.net/ProggerPete/edTWS/4/

Comment: And the specific reason I'm trying to avoid manual bindings is that I think the parent view model will retain a reference to the combobox model after I call cleanNodes if I subscribe manually. Although, thinking about it more, this is probably going to be an issue with dependent observables too...

Comment: What you can do is use: `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback` to add a callback to dispose of the subscription, when cleanNode is called on the main element.  Added a code snippet in the answer to show what it might look like for you.